# How to check if row exists in mysql, in Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I would like to check in the record exists in mysql, I am working in Node js. My code is:

```
//Some code before where I get classes

for (var m = 0; m <= (classes.length-1); m++) {
    var Myurl = classes[m];

    (function(Myurl){
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'mydatabase',
        });
        connection.connect();

        //How do I write the query correctly?
        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1', [Myurl], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) 
                throw err;

            SqlNames = rows;
            logNames();

            //If UrlLink is not present in mydatabase, then I want to proceed with:
            request(Myurl,  function(err, resp, body) {
                // ...
            }
        });

        function logNames() {
            console.log(SqlNames);
        }

        connection.end();
    };
})(Myurl);
```

So, I want to check if a record exists in my database, and if it does not exist I want to process with the request, and add it to the database. Now I get an error:

> connection is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your connection is undefined is because you are creating it in a JavaScript closure. When you initialize a variable inside a function, its scope prevents it from being accessed from outside that function.

Here is some sample code:

```
var Myurl = classes[m];
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ // Notice how this is not in a function?
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'mydatabase',
});
connection.connect();
// Just like before.
```

Without knowing your database schema, I cannot tell you if that is the proper query, but it looks correct for what you are doing.